# How to setup a standalone SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering what would be the way to go about setting up a standalone external SQL server so that all my programs can connect to it for testing and developing. Any help, even if it's yelling at me saying I'm posting on the wrong site is helpful in pointing me in the right direction thank you.

EDIT------
Just for clarification MySQL or SQL is acceptable with MySQL being preferred.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want a SQL Server or a mysql

- **SQL Server**: You have [SQL Server express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) for free.
- **MySql**: The best thing is that you install [LAMP](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack) (Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP) or [WAMP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/) if you use Windows.

You can install only MySQL in [Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html) or [Linux](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-installation.html) if you don't use Php & Apache (for example if your app is in .NET)

Comment: Well right now I am trying to setup a line server with LAMP and using that but for some reason I can't get it to work as a standalone database server I connect to so I'm looking for the way that others would go about doing such. SQL or MySQL is acceptable with MySQL being preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to segregate production from test an development.

Comment: Well what I would like is since I'm currently studying computer programming I'd like a standalone server for my databases for when I'm testing out certain apps and also as a learning experience for how to connect an application to a database on an external server.

Comment: Then simpply install SQL Server Express on your Windows, or MySQL on your Linux.

Comment: So box a is where you develop your apps and box b is the db server - are they on you home network?

Comment: No im trying to use a Linode server as a standalone database server while I develop my programs on my home network.

Comment: I don't have any experience with linode so I'm going to butt out here. I will say that a quick look at the linode website indicates that this is a LINUX hosting site so MSSQL isnt't an option (yet). If you google Linode mysql there's a load of stuff in googleland. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah this question was more of a "How would all the other people who use databases set this up for themselves" as a way of me to learn from people who have used a standalone database server.